# Tag description that is possibly unsuitable for an English language site

Tags: discussion, tags

The description for our (main site's) third most popular tag [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) reads:

> This tag is for questions which a dictionary cannot answer about what a word means.

This sentence seems ..off to me, if not entirely wrong—I would never phrase it like that, in any case.
Can a native English speaker defend this usage, or can it be altered?

Comment: It might benefit from parenthetical commas, parentheses, or em dashes: This tag is for questions, _which a dictionary cannot answer,_ about what a word means. Other than that I think it's fine.

Comment: Or simply a reordering: *This tag is for questions about what a word means which a dictionary cannot answer.* (though a comma after *means* would help here too)

Comment: It's good grammar, but poor style as both the "which" and "about" phrases modify the simple noun "questions". @Glorfindel's rewording is my suggestion too because the "which" phrase modifies "questions about what a word means".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see that the text has been updated, but it still includes a parenthetical comma, making "which a dictionary cannot answer" nonrestrictive. However, if that clause were removed, then the meaning of the sentence would change to something that I don't think we want. (After all, if the dictionary can answer the meaning of a word, then there would presumably be no reason for such a question.)